# SQLCMD Error 0xc000007b

Tags: sql-server, sql, windows-server-2019, visual-c++

**The Environment:**

- Windows Server 2019 Standard
- SQL Server 2019 Standard
- [SQL CMDLINE Utitlies V15 for x64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [ODBC Driver 17 for x64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

**The Problem:**
I am trying to run the `sqlcmd` command in Powershell and Command Prompt. When I run it in PowerShell such as `sqlcmd -?` nothing happens, it just returns to `c:\Windows\system32\`. When I run `sqlcmd -?` in Command Prompt it throws the following error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
> to close the application.

I am not sure why I am getting this error. This is nothing in the system logs. I did find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1133883/64-bit-files-in-system32) fix  on here but I have Visual C++ Redistributables from 2005, 2008, 2012, 2013, 2015-2019 for the software I have running on the server. Many of those running both x86 an x64 versions.

**The Question:**
What is causing the 0xc000007b error from allowing me to run my `sqlcmd` command? And if it is an issue with the Visual C++ version, do I need all the previous year versions or can I remove all of those and just use the 2015-2019 versions (x64 & x86) as they are the latest? And to fix this issue would I do a repair of those Redistributables or uninstall or reinstall?

**UPDATE** Uninstalled the CMDLINE tools for 32 bit and installed 64bit tools and still can't get `sqlcmd -?` to show anything. If I invoke the .exe and use the commands nothing happens. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Does the PATH variable contain the sqlcmd folder?

Comment: My (high level) guess is that your setup is trying to intermix 32 and 64 bit components (probably at the ODBC layer).  You likely are running a 32bit .exe with a 64bit ODBC driver or visa versa.

Comment: @harrymc Yes the the sqlserver Folder is in the PATH and PSModulePath for the server Environments.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes I removed the x86 SQLCMD tools and reinstalled the x64 tools while the ODBC is still x64 rand still get nothing in return when I do 'sqlcmd -?'

Comment: Try looking for missing dependencies using [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) for `sqlcmd.exe`.

Comment: @harrymc it is saying BatchParser.dll is not on the disk even though it is in the same folder that SQLCMD is. Also it says ODBC32.dll has missing imports. I am confused as to why it says it's not on the disk. Also I have the 64 bit version installed by is it referenceing system 32 or the ODBC for 32 bit?

Comment: The reason could be a mixture of 32- and 64-bit software. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows).

Comment: Also, file in same folder has priority over the PATH.

Comment: @harrymc according to that answer the SQLCMD is PE  d† meaning 64 bit.

Comment: And what is `BatchParser.dll`?

Comment: @harrymc not sure but when I ran dependencies it showed as an issue.

Comment: If SQLCMD is 64-bit but `BatchParser.dll` is 32-bit then it's unusable for SQLCMD.

Comment: @harrymc how can you tell the difference?

Comment: [How to Check if a Program (.EXE or .DLL) is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-out-if-a-program-exe-file-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/).

Comment: @harrymc should I do a full uninstall of everything SQL and reinstall?

Comment: Yes, you could. Ensure that the installation folders were fully cleaned out, and that the installation you do all softwares are of the same bitness.